# PHP Script that receives information from specified websites

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am trying to create a script that will gather information from Amazon product listing based on entered product ASIN (description, image, price, seller name). Functionality should be similar to this one: http://www.savings.com/pricejump

I tried to use DOM to receive HTML elements but I am concerned about IP ban if I have too many requests in short period of time.  I plan to have several hundred requests per day with this script.

Can you please share some useful links on this subject. I really don't know in which direction to head.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use their affiliate program, which is free and would allow enough requests to accomplish what you asked. Plus it provides a web services API, which is much cleaner and easier to use than screen scraping.

https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html